# Views pager labels translation per context

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

Now that I finally have managed to have Views pagers appear, I'm wondering how I could change the strings collection (prev, next, first, last...) per View. That's because in a View that displays items in chronological manner, I would rather see labels like older/newer rather than previous/next. Can this be done somewhere in views template or in template.php? (No jquery here, please :))

Answer (score 0):

Use hook_pager() in your theme template.

```
function YOUR_THEME_pager($tags) {
  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($tags);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```